# Shell_NotifyIcon() fails with "invalid window handle" if job object has JOB_OBJECT_UILIMIT_HANDLES restriction

Tags: windows, winapi, window, msdn

When I tried to use sandboxing I've been using for other processes to one in which I'm creating a notification tray icon, I get "invalid window handle" when calling Shell_NotifyIcon() to add the icon, unless I remove the JOB_OBJECT_UILIMIT_HANDLES from the process' job object. Microsoft states that this limit "Prevents processes associated with the job from using USER handles owned by processes not associated with the same job." So how does this apply here? The window handle I pass into the notify icon structure is of a window created by the process itself. Is Shell_NotifyIcon() internally accessing some other USER object handle? Microsoft also states that UserHandleGrantAccess() can be used to bypass the restriction for individual handles, but, again, I don't know which handle is the issue.
(Note: I'm also aware that Shell_NotifyIcon() doesn't reliably set the last error, so "invalid window handle" could be misleading).

Comment: The Shell_NotifyIcon function needs to notify the taskbar about the new icon. The task bar is a window from a process not in the job. The upshot is that jobs under UI handle restrictions cannot use Shell_NotifyIcon. There are many other things that use window handles behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks, please post it as an answer. I forgot the taskbar and its notification area have handles. I have things working now by doing UserHandleGrantAccess() on the results of FindWindowEx() for "Shell_TrayWnd". One thing is that I'm using CreateDesktop() to prevent shatter attacks, so I enumerate all taskbars and grant access to all of them. Is there a way to check whether a given taskbar's HWND belongs to a specific desktop? It's not a big issue since the sandboxed process has a restricted token using a denied ACL which I've inserted into the original desktop, but it'd be cleaner.

Comment: By the way, it looks like it's not also necessary to grant access to "TrayNotifyWnd" which is a child of "ShellTray_Wnd" (also, trying to give only access to the child, notification area handle, appears to be insufficient).